# How to compare the strings?

Tags: objective-c

In my project i am adding  many words to a list from another view controller and i need to check that the words cannot be same in the list.
Here is the code ,please help where i need to do that

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{
    if ([listName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please enter List Name." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [error show];
    } else if (self.newlist) {
        if (listName.text.length > 0  ) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
            NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
            NSString *dateString =  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

            if (notification.on ) {
                NSString *dateStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",dateString, time.text ];

                [self saveList:dateStr:dateString];
                [self saveListImages];
                [self getlistdata];
            }else {
                [self saveList:@"2000-01-01 00:00":dateString];
            }
        }else{
            [listName becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for `saveList`, `saveListImages`, and `getlistdata` methods.

Comment: Store the string in an `NSSet`, since the a `NSSet` cannot contain more then one object with the same value. The value is based on the has of the object. You can therefor not store the same string twice in the a `NSSet` and you can use the `containsObject` if the string is already in the set.

Comment: Not getting it properly ...can u specify more??    in my code i am comparing the list names .Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your string in a mutable array and call below comparator to check for duplicates. Below code ensures case insensitive checks so it won't allow `TEST` and `test` go in the same array.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"TEST", @"Data"]];

NSString *testString = @"Test";

NSInteger index = [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return (BOOL)([obj caseInsensitiveCompare:testString] == NSOrderedSame);
}];

if (index != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"String already entered. Throw error");
} else {
    [myArray addObject:testString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSOrderedSet *uniqueWordSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:arrayWithDuplicates];
NSArray *unwiqueWordList = uniqueWordSet.array; // If you need it as array
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.